# Suggestions on how to build an actogram in R?

Tags: r, graph

I'm studying activity patterns in animals, and I have 4 months worth of activity measures taken every 5 minutes for multiple individuals. What I would love is to build an actogram from this data as seen in [this article](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0114143). Each horizontal line of the actogram represents a day, and the colour varies with the intensity of activity.

Apparently there is an actogram package for R, but I can't get it to load after trying it on multiple computers. With this:

```
install.packages("actogram", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I get back

> install.packages("actogram", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1
>
> package ‘actogram’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘actogram’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

My question is: is there a way to build an actogram in R without using this package? I'm relatively new to R and not very computer-savvy, but if it's possible, I'm willing to learn! I just can't find a whole lot of information about this type of graph or how to go about constructing one.

Basically, I just need to build a row of 24 coloured squares, each square representing an hourly mean, and each colour corresponding to a defined activity range. But I need to keep stacking these rows (each representing a day) on top of each other...

Thanks!!

Comment: if you don't want to use their package, you can look at the [source code](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/actogram.R?view=markup&root=actogram) and try to figure it out. The package hasn't been built since 2012 looks like, so you'd have to build it from source using your current r version

Comment: As the error message says, a binary is not available. Try: `install.packages("actogram", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")` If you are on Windows, you may need to install [RTools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to compile packages from source

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - I didn't know what binary not available meant, but the line MrFlick wrote worked, which is awesome, thank you! Unfortunately as it turns out, it doesn't seem like that was what was used to make those beautiful coloured actograms after all, so I'm back to square one - but at least now I know. Maybe I can try to make sense of the code in the link rawr provided to get it to do something a little different...

Comment: The quickest solution I seem to have found so far is using heatmap.2 from the gplots package which will construct (as far as I can tell) essentially the same thing as an actogram anyway...